# Total possible ways + ensuring order

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> I was thinking a problem(concurrency related problem in operating system but involve basic maths). There are k programs each with $m_1, m_2,...m_k$ steps. Programs execute concurrently. But i need to maintain order of steps in each program say $P_i : 1, 2, 3, ...m_i$ (i+1 step can only be performed only after performing ith step). In how many ways i can execute k programs concurrently.

---

> My attempt:

Total there are $(m_1+m_2+...m_k)!$ ways. But each 1 to $m_i$ must be executed in same order. $m_i!$ ways - fraction to ensure order = $1/m_i!$

So required number of ways out of total possible ways = $\frac{1}{m_1!}\frac{1}{m_3!}\frac{1}{m_3!}....\frac{1}{m_k!}*(m_1+m_2+...m_k)! $ ways

Can you pls tell me is this correct?

Comment: This is correct. You can look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

Comment: Sir i read multiset permutation. It is how many arrangements of n letter word with some words with multiplicities $m_1, m_2....m_k$. (for ex,, anagrams of MISSISSIPPI = 11!/(4! 4! 2!).. Answer is same but how my case is same as multiset permutation. What happens if in that anagram, there are 4 S's.  now i forceable lable them as s1, s2,s3,s4. I want now anagram of particular order say s1, s2, s3, s4. Please explain. I am reading this for the first time. I am not good in this part.

Comment: I have another Qn. We have num of anagrams of word MISSISSIPPI. Like selecting r out of n(normal selection), how many ways we can select r letters out of that word MISSISSIPPI. It becomes complex right due to multiplicities?

Comment: If you do not delete by 4! for the case of four S's, you allow all variants of arranging s1,...,s4 appears. And among 4! permutations of this numbers, exactly one permutation when this numbers follow one to another in increasing order. So 1/4! from all permutations of this numbers satisfies your condition. And the same with other repeating letters.

Comment: Yes, it becomes complex.

Comment: thank you sir, understood now ..